# How do I extend the amount of frames on a 2d animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, timeline

I need to extend the amount of frames on the timeline, as you can see in the picture it ends around **1020 frames** in the png. I havent tried anything yet to fix it myself but I was wondering if there was a way to go about fixing it before I do any unrepairable damage to the file. Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number of frames for the project if you type it at the bottom right of the timeline window.

[image]

Note that you've enabled an alternative preview range, that is different than the project's frame range.

[image]

> **Preview Range**(clock icon)
> This is a temporary frame range used for previewing a smaller part of the full range. The preview range only affects the viewport, not the rendered output.

Read:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html?highlight=preview%20range